# Can someone tell me what this crazy c++ statement means in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, porting

First off, no I am not a student...just a C# guy porting a C++ library.

What do these two crazy lines mean? What are they equivalent to in C#? I'm mostly concerned with the size_t and sizeof. Not concerned about static_cast or assert..I know how to deal with those.

```
size_t Index = static_cast<size_t>((y - 1620) / 2);
assert(Index < sizeof(DeltaTTable)/sizeof(double));
```

y is a double and DeltaTTable is a double[]. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay, I got it. In the second line, the expression to the right of the operator is determining the length of the array, just like accessing the Length property on a C# array or IEnumerable type. Since DeltaTTable is an array of doubles, sizeof gets the number of memory units that DeltaTTable occupies. Then that value is divided by the number of memory units that a double takes up. This will give you the LENGTH of the array. It's a way to make sure that length is the same, regardless of the underlying machine architecture.

Comment: So yeah, the first line equates to "int Index = (int)((y -1620) / 2);" The second line equates to "if (Index < DeltaTTable.Length) throw new Exception();"...because assert will terminate the C++ program if it doesn't evaluate to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size_t` is a typedef for an unsigned integer type. It is used for sizes of things, and may be 32 or 64 bits in size. The particular size of a `size_t` is implementation defined, but it is *unsigned*.

I suppose in C# you could use a 64-bit unsigned integer type.

All `sizeof` does is return the size in bytes of a C++ type. Every type takes up a certain quantity of room, and `sizeof` returns that size.

What your code is doing is computing the number of doubles (64-bit floats) that the `DeltaTTable` takes up. Essentially, it's ensuring that the table is larger than some size based on `y`, whatever that is.

There is no equivalent of `sizeof` in C#, nor does it need it. There is no reason for you to port this code to C#.

Comment: y is the fractional representation of a year. And perfect answer, thank you. I was just forming the same conclusion. Cheers! I'll accept in a minute...when SO lets me!

Comment: Well he could crude way calculate sizeof a type in c#, though may not be soo accurate i guess. if its ref type, then all memebers in it + 2 byte points + uptill object class heirarchy * 2 byte pointers.

Comment: @Nicol - C# does indeed have an operator `sizeof`. It's used to calculate the size of the built-in, enum, pointer types, as well as user defined structs that don't contain any reference type fields or members. Used like this: `var x = sizeof(int); // == 4`

Answer (score 3):

The bad news first you can't do that in C#. There's no static cast only dynamic casts. However the good news is it doesn't matter.

The two lines of code is asserting that the index is in bounds of the table so that the code won't accidentally read some arbitrary memory location. The CLR takes care of that for you. So when porting just ignore those lines they are automatically there for you any ways.

Of course this is based on an assumption based on the pattern of the code. There's no information on what Y represents and how Index is used

Comment: Best answer as it describes the intent of the two lines (bounds checking).

Answer (score 0):

sizeOf calculates how much memory in bytes the DeltaTable type takes. 
There is not equivalent to calculate the size like this in c# AFAIK.

I guess size_t much be a struct type in C++ code.

Comment: From what I can tell, size_t is basically an unsigned int. Hmm...well, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @GWW size_t is normaly a typedef to represent the size of an array. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstddef/size_t/

Comment: I think Zenwalker is correct, sizeof calculates how much memory in bytes DeltaTable type takes. Size_t is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_t